# Deleted .bash_profile, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I've made a series of mistakes so I will walk you through what happened.

Something was obviously wrong with my bash (or so I assume, maybe I am wrong) because every time I opened a new terminal window I had to reinstall Ruby to the newest version as well as reinstall Rails completely.

Finally I decided to reinstall RVM and when I checked the version it was telling me my PATH was off. I tried fixing my PATH but was told that 'export: Command not found'. So I deleted my .bash_profile assuming it would reset. Everything seemed dandy at first because when I checked the RVM version again it didn't give me the PATH warning (now I think I realize that's because there was absolutely no path).

To further complicate matters I had previously made my .bashrc reference my .bash_profile, so no love there either.

Could someone please help point me in the right direction to rebuild my .bash_profile, I think from there I can follow the Rails Installfest (http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/osx_rvm), but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Also attached is a picture of my current terminal, which looks like something is off. Actually apparently I can't post pictures so I will tell you, before my prompt in terminal it reads "[username:~] username%"

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'd really like to get in to coding and not let this stop me but I don't know where else to turn...!

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: @Carl: ".../osx_rvm", so presumably OS X. Which version is it? Why you "had to reinstall Ruby"? How did you install it in the first place? By default, OS X has Ruby already installed, did you install another one? There is nothing in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` that you normally *need*; RVM might put something in it when it installs.

Comment: I suggest you `rvm implode` then reinstall it following the instructions from https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: @Amadan "RVM might put something in it when it installs." And that's what I hate the most about RVM; it litters every single rc file, by default, *without user's permissions*.

Comment: @4ae1e1: I have no intention of uninstalling RVM, so the fact that it places something non-destructive into my rc files that is required for it to give me the comfort of use that I installed it for is a non-issue for me. This is not a forum to start religious wars.

Comment: @Amadan I use RVM and like pretty much everything else about it, so I have no intention to start religious wars. Just pointing out a personal sentiment (and that's clearly considered bad practice), as you mentioned that. Oh, and that *is* destructive. One either prompts before littering user rc files that don't belong to the program, or prints information to console and let users do it by themselves.

Comment: Ok guys I figured it out. again I am still brand new to all of this so this might be one hell of a circular process but here goes. I noticed my prompt changed a while ago, so I uninstalled Xcode and rebooted to see if that solved anything. Nope. Reinstalled Xcode and still nothing. Turns out I never accepted the user agreement to Xcode again.

Somewhere along the lines my terminal starting running in tcsh. I installed oh my zsh to see if my terminal was responding at all and nothing. That's when I learned about tcsh. I uninstalled zsh and went back to bash but my .bash_profile was empty so ...

Comment: it just kept logging in and running programs and then saying "process completed". I set the PATH in my .bash_profile but it kept yelling at me about matching " even though they match (from what I could see). But more importantly my PATH was set! So I deleted everything out of my .bash_profile and things were getting back to normal. I installed RVM again but it couldn't find it, so I had to update my .bash_profile with the source of RVM. Once bash could find RVM, my latest versions of Ruby & Rails were back and I'm back in business. Took me a few hours but I learned a lot!